# Using external file for suite names in protractor

Tags: selenium, protractor

I need some help to parameterize my test suites.

I want to create a Json file Suites.json and define suites in this file

```
module.exports = {
Suites: 
Smoke: 'File1.spec.js','File2.spec.js',
Main: 'File1.spec.js','File2.spec.js','File3.spec.js'
}
```

Now i want to use this Json file in protractor.conf.js
I imported JSON file:

```
var SuiteFile = require('../Suites.json')
```

Now if i want to us in my actual Conf file, i am not sure how to use it.

Should i just say:

```
suites: SuitesFile
```

Can someone please confirm?

Comment: Why not try? The suites should be arrays of strings, not the weird non-js notation you tried with comma separation. Check out http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/object-literal/ for object literal syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely possible to do something like this. 
Please refer [my blog](https://testautomation-aditya.com/2016/12/27/how-to-externalize-suite-namespick-from-an-external-file-in-protractor/) post for more info

Step 1: Create a js file with suites

```
module.exports = {
suitesCollection: {
    smoke: ['File1.spec.js','File2.spec.js',],
    sanity: ['File1.spec.js','File2.spec.js','File3.spec.js'],
    demo: ['demo.js']
}
}
```

Step 2: Import the js file and point the exports.config.suites to use the info from this file

```
var suitesFile = require('./suites.js');

exports.config = {
    suites: suitesFile.suitesCollection,
```

UPDATE: In case there is a need to use Json feed for suites, please refer below

Step 1: Create a JSON file with Key-Value pairs of suites

```
{
  "smoke": "demo.js,demo2.js",
  "sanity": "demo2.js,demo.js,demo3.js",
  "demo": "demo.js"
}
```

Step 2: Import the JSON and edit the config file accordingly. In case you want the suite names also generated, create a custom function to iterate the JSON and build suites

```
var suitesJson = require('./suites.json');

    exports.config = {
    suites: {
    smoke: suitesJson.smoke.split(","),
    sanity: suitesJson.sanity.split(","),
    demo: suitesJson.demo.split(",")
},
```

**OR** In case you need to completely construct Suites object out of JSON (when you dont even know suite names)

Protractor Config File

```
var suitesJson = require('./suites.json');
var suitesAll = {}
for(var myKey in suitesJson) {
    suitesAll[myKey] = suitesJson[myKey].split(",");
}
    exports.config = {
    suites: suitesAll,
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked great. Can you please let me know what is different if i put it in json file instead of .js file? I want to have this in an excel and import it during run time for easy maintenance.

Comment: yes, Using JSON is also very much possible. I have updated the answer

Comment: Thank you Aditya. You are a rockstar. One last question - I am not sure if you worked on Jenkins or not. May be i should direct my question to Jenkins community. I want my Jenkins to show smoke, sanity and demo in parameter name while running. Do you know how should i be able to achieve this?

Comment: In above example, i do not want names of suites in config file so that i can just modify my global suite file instead of going inside each conf.js file. Is it possible in json like how you did in js? Is there any way we can assign whole collection instead of splitting it?

Comment: np .. and reg Jenkins .. yes you can have build parameters .. May be little googling will get you that done.   Reg constructing suites out of JSON I have updated JSON

Comment: Need one help. I have a long path name with every spec name. so my actual path inside project folder is /specs/sites/Project1/File1.spec.js I have many specs to be listed. Is it possible to store common path for all specs in a variable and just list file name inside JSON file? How should i access that fixed path name in conf.js with my file name?