# Reading parameters in Jenkins from .js or Json file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, extended-choice-parameter

I have a .js or json file where all my parameters are defined. I want to use this file and have Jenkins read these parameter name from file during build and display such that Suite1 is displayed one job and parameters for Suite2 in another.
For Suite1, jenkins should show smoke and default however for Suite 2 it should show default and Testing in drop down. Can anyone please suggest right way to do it?

```
module.exports = {
Suite1: { 
smoke: ['file1.spec.js','file2.spec.js],
default: ['file3.spec.js']
},
Suite2: {
default: ['file2.spec.js'],
Testing: ['file2.spec.js']
}
}
```

I tried [extended Choice parameter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin) but not getting desired results as there is no way of importing Json file as parameter in there.

Comment: Answered something similar here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758088/using-external-file-for-suite-names-in-protractor

Comment: @AdityaReddy This post it to get information about Jenkins. I am still not able to work Jenkins to fetch parameters.

Comment: @malenkiy_scot  It seems you have answered Extended choice parameter and jenkins questions in past. Can you please have a look at my question as well?